# ScriptingBridge Finder POSIX path

Tags: objective-c, finder, scripting-bridge

is it possible to get the POSIX path or target to the frontmost window using the Scripting Bridge framework?

I'm using

```
FinderApplication *theFinder = [SBApplication aplicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Finder";
```

but I can't find anything in "Finder.h" that could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you are after using ScriptingBridge and NSURL

```
FinderApplication *finder = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.finder"];

SBElementArray *windows =  [finder windows ]; // array of finder windows
NSArray *targetArray = [windows arrayByApplyingSelector:@selector(target)];// array of targets of the windows

//gets the first object from the targetArray,gets its URL, and converts it to a posix path
NSString * newURLString =   [[NSURL URLWithString: (id) [[targetArray   objectAtIndex:0]URL]] path];

NSLog(@"newURLString   %@  ", newURLString);
```

Comment: Glad it helped,
Remember to put it in something like  a try / catch block, or you will get a 'beyond bounds' error if no windows are open.

Answer (score 2):

Running drawnonward's code through [appscript's](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) ASTranslate tool gives me this:

```
#import "FNGlue/FNGlue.h"
FNApplication *finder = [FNApplication applicationWithName: @"Finder"];
FNReference *ref = [[[finder windows] at: 1] target];
FNGetCommand *cmd = [[ref get] requestedType: [ASConstant alias]];
id result = [cmd send];
```

The result will be an ASAlias instance; use -[ASAlias path] to get the POSIX path.

You can't do it in SB short of resorting to raw Apple event codes as that's one of the features the Apple engineers forgot/didn't bother to put into SB's [less than stellar API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309958/avoiding-applescript-through-ruby-rb-appscript-or-rubyosa/1316563#1316563).

Comment: Addendum: Finder's designers were good enough to include a `URL` property that will give you a file URL string. With a bit of fiddling, you might persuade SB to retrieve that value, at which point you can use NSURL to convert that a POSIX path string.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used ScriptingBridge.  As part of an NSAppleScript it would be:

```
get POSIX path of (target of window 1 as alias)
```

Hopefully that helps.  I think the POSIX part is from the StandardAdditions ScriptingAddition, not the Finder itself.