# Working with a file by pathname/URI using Finder + ScriptingBridge

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, scripting-bridge

I'm using the generated Finder.h headers from the sdef utility, and it appears that a lot of Finder SB methods require objects of type FinderItem to do anything meaningful with.

How would I go about creating one of them objects based on a path to or URI of the file?

The farthest I've got is the [SBObject initWithProperties] method briefly mentioned in the SB guide but have no clue where to go from there. The basic AppleScript I'd like to translate into Objective-C is then, to put it yet another way:

```
set myFile to POSIX file 
  "/untitled folder/funneh/keyboardcat.mov"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about `SBObject`, but if you want a `FinderItem*`, this is how you could get one.

```
NSString* pathString = [@"/untitled folder/funneh/keyboardcat.mov" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSURL* theFileURL = [pathString fileURLWithPath:pathString];
FinderApplication* finder = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.finder"];
FinderItem * theItem = [[finder items] objectAtLocation: theFileURL];
```

Comment: I don't have Xcode handy here but it does look like the right idea. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the `FinderItem` object then slf's code will work if you change the line:

```
NSURL* theFileURL = [pathString fileURLWithPath:pathString];
```

to

```
NSURL* theFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathString];
```

But if you want a HFS style path then I found this snippet.

```
NSString* path = [(NSString*)CFURLCopyFileSystemPath((CFURLRef)theFileURL, kCFURLHFSPathStyle) autorelease];
 NSLog(@"path= %@",path);
```

Which returns a string of "Hard Disk:untitled folder:funneh:keyboardcat.mov"

The snippet can be found [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?FileNameFromString).

Comment: Handy. Thanks for the snippet!

Answer (score 0):

After reading a [very detailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309958/avoiding-applescript-through-ruby-rb-appscript-or-rubyosa) AppleScript related answer, I decided to stick with [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/), which made things much easier:

```
FNApplication *finder = [[FNApplication alloc] initWithName:@"Finder.app"];
FNReference *ref = [[finder files] byName: @"/users/movies/kitteh.mov"];
```