# Retrieve system volume and mute status in ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, volume, audiotoolbox, mute

Is there a clean way to detect whether the default output device (on Mac OS X) is being muted via a ruby program?

I know I can make a system call to an applescript or mangle together something with objective-c cocoa calls. But I'd like something built-in or a tried-and-true gem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple Ruby to AppleScript gems:

- [Appscript](https://github.com/mattneub/appscript)
- [RubyOSA](http://rubyosa.rubyforge.org/)

According to [Avoiding AppleScript through Ruby: rb-appscript or rubyosa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309958/avoiding-applescript-through-ruby-rb-appscript-or-rubyosa), Appscript is superior, but neither is compiling cleanly for me (OSX 10.10.2, Ruby 2.2.2), and this is a very simple use case, so I'd go with your own call out to `osascript`. The RubyTunes gem to control iTunes from Ruby [went this direction](https://github.com/drn/rubytunes/blob/master/lib/rubytunes/script.rb), and the AppleScript [sound controls](https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-control-os-x-system-volume-with-applescript/) are easy:

```
osascript -e "output muted of (get volume settings)"
false
```

Comment: I want to avoid applescript since it invokes launchservicesd which is power intensive. I'd like to call this many times a minute and the applescript version is draining my battery.